# Uniformly Load 128-bit Data from Constant Memory

Tags: types, vector, cuda, structure, gpgpu

Given a CUDA vector type `int4`, how can I load 128 bits of data from constant memory.

This doesn't seem to work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>

__constant__ int constant_mem[4];
__global__ void kernel(){
    int4 vec;
    vec = constant_mem[0];
}
int main(void){return 0;}
```

On the seventh line I'm trying to load all 4 integer values in the constant memory into the 128-bit vector type. This operation results in the following compilation error:

```
vectest.cu(7): error: no operator "=" matches these operands
            operand types are: int4 = int
```

Also, is it possible to access the vector type directly without having to cast it, like so:

```
int data = vec[0];
```

Switch statement in PTX assembly:

```
    @%p1 bra    BB1_55;

    setp.eq.s32     %p26, %r1, 1;
    @%p26 bra   BB1_54;

    setp.eq.s32     %p27, %r1, 2;
    @%p27 bra   BB1_53;

    setp.ne.s32     %p28, %r1, 3;
    @%p28 bra   BB1_55;

    mov.u32     %r961, %r61;
    bra.uni     BB1_56;

BB1_53:
    mov.u32     %r961, %r60;
    bra.uni     BB1_56;

BB1_54:
    mov.u32     %r961, %r59;
    bra.uni     BB1_56;

BB1_55:
    mov.u32     %r961, %r58;

BB1_56:
```

Comment: More context please. What does "doesn't work" mean? Showing a code snippet where the types and memory spaces are not defined isn't very helpful. Ideally code you post should be short and completely self contained. It makes the job of those who might help you uh easier when they don't have to guess or ask for clarification in comments (like in your last question)

Comment: @talonmies Sorry I wasn't clear, I mean to say the code won't compile. I've updated the question to include the compilation error. I've also included the basic piece of code I'm trying to compile.

Comment: It sounds like you want something like `vector = * reinterpret_cast<int4 *>(&constant_mem)` for the first case, but why not just access the members in the int4 in the second? Am I missing something else here?

Comment: @talonmies I've figured out a workaround for the first case by actually declaring the constant memory as int4. For the second case, I need to access the data based on the thread ID. So I cant access it as  by simply using vector.x, vector.y, etc. I could maybe cast the data as an array of ints, but I'm not sure that would be safe, it also wouldn't be very clean looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, casting is probably the simplest solution, so something like this:

```
__constant__ int constant_mem[4];
__global__ void kernel(){
    int4 vec = * reinterpret_cast<int4 *>(&constant_mem);
}
```

(disclaimer written in browser, not compiled or tested, use at own risk)

Using the C++ `reinterpret_cast` operator will force compiler will emit a 128 bit load instruction.

In the second case, it sounds like you want to directly address 32 bit words stored in an array of 128 bit vector types, using 128 bit memory transactions. That requires some helper functions, perhaps something like:

```
__inline__ __device__ int fetch4(const int4 val, const int n)
{
     (void) val.x; (void) val.y; (void) val.z; (void) val.w;
     switch(n) {
         case 3:
            return val.w;
         case 2: 
            return val.z;
         case 1:
            return val.y;
         case 0:
         default:
            return val.x;
    }
}

__device__ int index4(const int4 * array, const int n)
{
    int div = n / 4;
    int mod = n - (div * 4);

    int4 val = array[div]; // 128 bit load here

    return fetch4(val, mod);
}

__constant__ int constant_mem[128];
__global__ void kernel(){
    int val = index4(constant_mem, threadIdx.x);
}
```

(disclaimer written in browser, not compiled or tested, use at own risk)

Here we force a 128 bit transaction by reading whole `int4` values and parsing their contents (the casts to void are an incantation necessary for older versions of the open64 compiler which was prone to optimize vector loads if it thought members were unused). There are a few IOPs of overhead to do the indexing, but they are potentially worth it if the load bandwidth of the resulting transaction is higher. The switch statement is probably compiled using conditional execution, so there shouldn't be a branch divergence penalty. Be aware that very random access to an array of int4 values can potentially waste a lot of bandwidth and cause warp serialization. There is potentially a big negative performance impact in doing so.

Comment: The accesses to the array of int4 values in my case won't be random. It will be accessed with fixed indices: array[0], array[1], etc., so the memory transactions shouldn't be serialized.

Comment: I took a lot at the PTX file generated by NVCC, it seems that your switch state does generate branches.

Comment: I've updated the question to include the PTX assembly generated. However, my program does appear to work. It makes use of warp-synchronicity, so it's rather confusing that these branches aren't breaking the program.

Comment: I did warn you that I hadn't compiled it. If the access isn't random and each index is known at compile time, the consider making the index argument to fetch4 a template argument. That will allow the compiler to optimise away the branches.

Comment: The access to the constant memory isn't random, but the vector is read into local memory where a 32-bit word is accessed based on the thread ID. I'm thinking maybe there's a cleaner way of doing this, but I should run a profile first and see how this new approach compares to my previous version of the program. I'll update you if you're still interested.

Comment: Ran a profile, got the same performance. I guess this is as good a performance s I'm going to get on my current hardware.